# Create a .docx file of custom data in android

Tags: java, android, sdk

How to create a .docx file of custom data and sent it to our mail in android ? As I saw docx4j jar to create is it useful or suggest me any other if anyone knows.

1.Is there any sdk or any api to create a .docx file?

2.or is there any custom method to create a .docx?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: I want to create a .docx file of custom data and send it to email and I dont have any idea how to implement this So I am asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **Apache POI** to create a `docx` file. Here is a good [quick guide](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_poi_word/apache_poi_word_quick_guide.htm).

Comment: Thanks for sharing useful link.